# Adding a custom annotation to a MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to add annotations to a `MKMapView`

I have created a class `CustomMapPin` which conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomMapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *type; // this is to differentiate between the different annotations on the map

@end
```

I have created a class `CustomMapAnnotationView` which is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`

**CustomMapAnnotationView.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomMapAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *annotationImage;
@end
```

**CustomMapAnnotationView.m**

```
#import "CustomMapAnnotationView.h"

@implementation CustomMapAnnotationView

-(id) initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 40);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.annotationImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 40)];
        self.annotationImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:self.annotationImage];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am adding the custom pins inside `FindMechanicViewController` which is a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `MKMapViewDelegate`

The code snippet is:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.currentLocation = [self.locationManager location];

    // Set the region of the map
    MKCoordinateSpan mapViewSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.currentLocation.coordinate, mapViewSpan);
    [self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion];

    // Add custom pin showing user location
    CustomMapPin *annotation = [[CustomMapPin alloc] init];
    annotation.title = @"Current Location";
    annotation.coordinate = self.currentLocation.coordinate;
    annotation.type = @"user location";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

And the delegate method

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *reuseId = @"CustomMapPin";
    CustomMapAnnotationView *annotationView = (CustomMapAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomMapPin class]]) {
        CustomMapPin *customAnnotation = (CustomMapPin *)annotation;

       if ([customAnnotation.type isEqualToString:@"user location"]) {
           [annotationView setAnnotation:customAnnotation];
           [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_user"]];
           [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        }

    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

This does not show anything on the map. How do I fix this ?

Comment: There are several issues with the code but a big one is that in viewForAnnotation, CustomMapAnnotationView is never actually alloc+inited (the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier does not do this).  If viewForAnnotation is even getting called, it must be returning nil which means map view must be putting a red pin _somewhere_.  Log the coordinates where the annotation is being added and look there.

Comment: That worked. I added another line initializing the annotationView if it was nil.

Comment: What other issues are there with the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, `CustomMapAnnotationView` is never actually alloc+inited (the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` does not do this).

If `viewForAnnotation` is even getting called, it must be returning `nil` which means the map view must be putting a red pin somewhere (and if the delegate method isn't getting called, then again the map view will default to a red pin).  Log the coordinates where the annotation is being added and look there.

A corrected `viewForAnnotation` might look like this:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomMapPin class]]) {
        static NSString *reuseId = @"CustomMapPin";

        CustomMapAnnotationView *annotationView = (CustomMapAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[CustomMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
            [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        }

        CustomMapPin *customAnnotation = (CustomMapPin *)annotation;

        //view's annotation should be set regardless of "type"
        [annotationView setAnnotation:customAnnotation];

        if ([customAnnotation.type isEqualToString:@"user location"]) {
            [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_user"]];
        }
        else {
            //If it's not a "user location", then set image
            //to something else otherwise image will either be nil
            //or it will show some other annotation's image...
            [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_other"]];
        }

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Some other issues with the code:

1. In `viewWillAppear`, code is retrieving the location immediately after calling `startUpdatingLocation`.  This is not guaranteed to work every time and even if it does "work", you will most likely be getting an old, cached location.  When it doesn't work, the annotation will either end up at 0,0 (Atlantic Ocean) or app will crash due to invalid coordinates.  It's much better to read the location in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.  In `viewWillAppear`, call `startUpdatingLocation` and then in `didUpdateLocations`, if the accuracy and age of the location is adequate for you, call `stopUpdatingLocation` and then use the location (create and add the annotation, etc).
2. In `CustomMapAnnotationView`, `annotationImage` object is created and added but its `image` property is never set.  The `annotationImage` is actually never really used for anything.
3. The whole `CustomMapAnnotationView` class is unnecessary for your purpose .  In `viewForAnnotation`, code is setting the `image` property on the `CustomMapAnnotationView` (instead of using `annotationImage`).  This `image` property is inherited from `MKAnnotationView`.  The built-in, basic `MKAnnotationView` class is all you need for what you're doing.  It already has an `image` property and it automatically displays it for you (you don't need to create your own `UIImageView`).